# Grafana & MYSQL - Visualise data in a table tracking weights

Tags: mysql, grafana

I have a very simple MYSQL table, which tracks the weights of some animals:

| id | name | weight | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Brillo | 400 | 2022-12-01 |
| 2 | Barli | 200 | 2022-12-01 |
| 3 | Bueno | 350 | 2022-12-01 |
| 4 | Brillo | 410 | 2022-12-10 |
| 5 | Barli | 197 | 2022-12-10 |
| 6 | Bueno | 362 | 2022-12-10 |

So in the example above, I weight my 3 animals on the 1st, then again on the 10th.

I would like to visualize this data in Grafana with a timeseries panel. I get the exact data I want, if I query the database once per pet:

```
SELECT name, weight as 'Brillo', date FROM animal.weights WHERE name='Brillo'
```

```
SELECT name, weight as 'Bueno', date FROM animal.weights WHERE name='Bueno'
```

```
SELECT name, weight as 'Barli', date FROM animal.weights WHERE name='Barli'
```

This gives me the following panel:
[image]

Whilst this works, doing 1 query per animal feels like the wrong approach. I will eventually have 20+ on here, so doing 20 queries to the database every time feels incorrect.

My question is this; Is there a way I can get the same results from my table into a Grafana timeseries panel in a single query?

```
SELECT name, weight, date FROM animals.weights
```

Comment: Yes, just pivot your table to have the names as columns and then select everything

Answer (score 0):

You need aggregation per `name` and `date` + also time filter (otherwise you will have a problem with a lot of records in the DB).

This is a good start:

```
SELECT 
  $__timeGroup(date, '1d', NULL),
  name AS "metric", 
  AVG(weight) AS "value"
FROM animals.weights
WHERE
  $__time(date)
ORDER BY 1
```

See [Grafana MySQL doc](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/mysql/#macros) for used macros.